# Is it safe to save user created javascript in database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a code playground type of application where a user(web developer/designer) can input HTML, CSS and Javascript and view the result on an iframe. The inputted code will be saved in the database (MySQL) and rendered back again in an iframe on a show_results view/action.

Now the question: Is it safe to save javascripts directly in the database? If not, then where/how should I save it?

Comment: It is safe to store the JS in any database. The risk comes when you retrieve that JS and render it to a page as a `<script>` block. But if you're going to re-create jsfiddle you have to take that risk.

Answer (score 1):

The database is not going to be your problem here.  It's fairly trivial to use prepared statements to allow all kinds of characters to be stored safely in the database.  Using anything other than prepared statements to store user input is insufficient, and essentially never recommended.

But you're talking about allowing arbitrary javascript to be executed, which is always going to be a security problem.  As a commenter above implies, you're going to be replicating the complexities of jsfiddle.net without the security experience, the development know-how, or the  express wish to keep on patching the vulnerabilities that will keep on cropping up.

Certainly you should be aware that what you're doing will completely compromise any domain that you set it up on, so that essentially that javascript should be only written on a throw-away domain or subdomain that you don't use for any other purpose.  Of course, it's going to be trivial in such an environment to simply framebreak and pull a viewer off of the site that hosts the frame as well.

I'm sure this just scratches the surface of the potential abuses that arbitrary javascript execution (aka intentional self cross-site-scripting) will bring with it.

Since you're essentially re-inventing a very dangerous wheel with this concept, why not simply use some of the embedding services that already exist out there?  codepen.io for example, allows you to embed it's snippets.

Comment: I'm building an app that uses the provisions of the technology behind a "code playground app" for an altogether different purpose. Codepen and CSSdeck are awesome, I agree with you. I'm willing to go through the catches of potential XSS attacks, patch them up and keep learning from it on my project. Would be awesome if you can suggest me write ups, best practices and places to start/refer from? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, what you're talking about (apart from the saving aspect which isn't excessively complicated once you use prepared statements) is all client side, so just copy jsfiddle or codepen or cssdeck, whichever is closest to what you actually want, and refine from there.  Just be sure to examine it's server headers and try to replicate those that seem necessary as well as well.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe as an architectural decision iff you are executing the javascript on the client side.

On any website you can use tools such as chrome's "inspect element" to manipulate the html, javascript etc on the client. Your system cannot assume that items on the client are not manipulated. This is why server side validation is still so important.

I completely disagree with kzqai. 
If this was the case then fiddler would be in serious trouble.

There are potential problems that can be exposed more easily with what you are doing, but those problems already exist and are just obscure.

IFF you are executing javascript on the server side, this is a very complex decision. I would personally avoid it if possible because the game you are playing is that you are able to catch every possible scenario for trouble vs a bad guy being able to catch the 1 you did not.

Comment: You essentially say to be very careful about executing javascript on the server side because it's a very complex decision, but then say that executing it on the client side is just fine, not at all a problem.  The only difference is who stands to get hurt.  Server side it's your server, client side it's your users.  If you think that jsfiddle is something that the developers were at all able to just "set it and forget it" without having to constantly patch new avenues of attack just because it's client side, well, you just aren't aware of the constant barrage of new client-side exploits.

Comment: That is not the case at all.

I agree that client side javascript can cause problems. However, you can never trust javascript of any kind in a web environment not to be executed on the client side. In fact you must assume the opposite.

For example, lets say a new threat comes out in the future. The threat is exploited with the following javascript code on the client side:

function beBad()
{
..
}

You cannot say "Well we are fine because we don't have that code". Instead you have to say and act upon the fact that IT WILL be executed. Therefore you need to handle that threat correctly.

Comment: By that logic, allowing arbitrary javascript to be stored in the db and executed on the client is in itself not a security threat.

A more concrete example would be:

Assume data is available IFF you have a security token.
Each user has their own token.
The javascript you are saving is allowed to be accessed by other users.
The data the token allows access to is considered confidential (lets just say identity information)
Allowing the javascript access to that token is obviously deadly because they could easily capture and transmit the token, thus granting access.

Comment: The problem here isn't actually the allowing of javascript. Instead the problem is the Token. I say that because plugins on chrome, other entry points, and a plethora of other problems exist. Instead you need to remove the token issue.

Answer (score -1):

It is safe as long as you correctly escape certain characters when inserting the value in the SQL statement. For example, if your Javascript code is:

```
var foo = 'hello world';
```

Then you will have to escape the single quotes when building the SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO snippets (code) VALUES ('var foo = ''hello world'';')
```

In the statement above, two single quotes ('') are the way to represent just a single quote in a string enclosed by single quotes.

See the link below for further information on escaping characters:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

**EDIT**

As Stephen P correctly points out, if you use prepared statements on the server side code then the framework under the hood will replace those characters for you.

Comment: You **don't** have to escape the quotes, or anything else, if you use Prepared Statements. Which you should do. Always.

Comment: Nice edits @Claudix - I point this out because I have a requirement that I need to store, exactly, _anything_ the user types in.  I therefore escape character when I _retrieve_ them from the database, and escape them depending on what they are being used for - HTML, JS, XML, etc.