# How to approach storing code snippets in a database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

for my side project, I want to make a React app that has a textarea where you can paste code snippets in it and then hit save. Then I will store it into a database linked to their user account id for later retrieval.

Are there any good approaches generally used to do something like this? For example, to turn my javascript into a string and store it in a JSON format to be sent off to firebase?

I wanted to try using encodeURI at first but I couldn't even store the code inside a variable yet. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'd appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 1):

This could be a possible duplication of [Is it safe to save user created javascript in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940061/is-it-safe-to-save-user-created-javascript-in-database)

Although the general consensus is the risk is not high storing it. But it is high while retrieving and injecting it in the DOM for rendering.

So you should be good storing the the data as a string. But you'll have to be updated about any possible security issues that might pop up later that needs patching.